# Calculate the size of things which are present in image

Tags: windows, images, image-recognition

Is there is any software which can calculate the size of things which are present on picture or image? For example, I have an image of furniture I want to calculate its length, width , height size of that furniture.  Is there is any approach or way?

P.S.: Cost of the software is not a concern, however I prefer free software. The operating system which I am using is Windows 7 so it should run on it.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. Especially missing: What OS should it run on, and what's your price margin?

Answer (score 0):

There might be software if you take a more feasible approach. Google Pixel phone apparently uses one camera but uses information from many video frames to determine depth. Depth is certainly required as a minimum for your needs.

There are more options available out there for determining depth if you use more than one camera - stereo vision. Details further away will have less accuracy though.

Even better if you have a radar or lidar.

Ultimately, you want to build a "point cloud" and then a 3d model of a scene. When the user chooses 2D points on the screen, they can be mapped to places in that 3D model and then measured.

You'll probably also need some kind of configuration step which adjusts for a given camera's lens and attributes.

Is there an off the shelf software for this? Not that I'm aware of. But each of the points above should help you break down your problem and find smaller components to use.

Answer (score 0):

Those available for the PC aren't very useful for your situation. They mainly work to determine angles and areas from maps or angles for smaller objects.

If you can photograph the item with your own phone, there are a number of apps available for both iOS and Android.

EasyMeasure (iOS and Android) bases the measurements on your camera's height off the floor. It works pretty well.

There are several others that base their measurements against the known dimensions of common objects that you can place in the photo.

From reading your question I figure you're a woodworker wanting to build a replica piece. If so, you might swing by one of the larger woodworking forums with a furniture area and ask around there, too. Best of luck on your project.